# Page Replacement Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, fault

i have a question and i am not sure about it. I would appreciate if someone could help. The question is like this:

The following sequence of requests for a program is taken from a 460 byte program: 10, 11, 104, 170, 73, 309, 185, 245, 246, 434, 458, 364 ((i.e there is one program in the memory which is 460 bytes long and it is referencing bytes within its text, and 10 means, 10th byte of the program is referenced, where 10 is a relative address). Main memory can hold a total of 200 bytes for this program. Indicate which requests result in page faults, and what is the number of page faults using the FIFO(first in first out) and optimal page replacement algorithms for a page size of 50 bytes.

Here is what i thought. First, since there is nothing in memory, the first request (10) causes a page fault. Then when the bytes 10 to 60 are loaded to memory since page size is 50 bytes. When the second request comes (11), it is not a page fault since it is already in the memory. Then 104 causes a page fault and the bytes between 104-154 are loaded to memory. 170 also causes page fault and 170-220 are loaded to memory, etc. etc. this goes like that. Is my logic true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably depends on whether the pages need to be aligned to 50-byte boundaries...

Comment: And there is also the lookahead / instruction prefetch, so the prefetching may occur in parallel with the actual execution. (that is why (conditional) jumps are so costly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Third request would cause bytes 100-149 to be loaded in memory because binary is virtually divided into 50-byte chunks and byte 104 would fall into the 3rd chunk.

You should also consider that physical memory can only hold 4 pages. At a certain point you might need to discard a page and re-trigger a page fault when it gets loaded.